# Does C Have a Standard Library For HTTP2

Tags: c, http, system, http2, spdy

**[Intro]**]

I have been practicing C for 4 Months 5 times a Week, I am attempting to make the best possible guess for moving into web server/client programming for HTTP2. I have worked with HTML5 & Javascript I also work with HTTP2 & have used SPDY on a low level.

**[Info]**

```
Debian GNU/Linux (Buster), V.10
```

Compiler - Clang
headers HTTP2(?)
Headers HTTP(sys/socket.h, sys/types.h, signal.h, arpa/inet.h)
Network Protocol - TCP, HTTP2, HTTP.

**[Question]**

When playing around with Java you notice a lot of `HTTP2` being used in Game engines. `HTTP2` is being standardized more & more in current languages as of 2021.(FOCUS POINT->) C has a standard Library for working with `HTTP` & `TCP`.
`HTTP2` uses Encryption & as of my knowledge is based in "`TCP`". Is there a standard for C working with, "`HTTP2 TCP`" types. I need to be able to read the Text from `HTTP2` & easily preform tasks(send(), recv().(<-FOCUS POINT END).

**[FINAL]**
Can I Realistically develop HTTP2 Programs Using C standard POSIX Library's.
How would I go about using HTTP2 in C & is it even posible.

Comment: No, there is no standard C library for HTTP2 or even HTTP. There are various Open Source libraries that provide HTTP/2 support. Do a search to find them and evaluate which one may work for your requirements. And yes, you certainly can write that from scratch but whether it is feasible or not depends on your own level of domain and programming expertise.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP is a *protocol*. It defines the way computers communicate with each other. There a lot of different protocols out there; HTTP/2 and HTTP is based on TCP/IP, which almost all computers use to connect to servers. TCP/IP specifies how to create a connection between a client and a specific server, and send raw bytes. HTTP(2) is a layer over this, which defines how a client should tell the server what resource it wants.

The API provided by base POSIX extends to only raw TCP/IP. Here's an example of what an application could send to a web server to request a web page (this is an HTTP/1 request, HTTP/2 is binary and encrypted, making it not human-readable)

```
GET /somepage HTTP/1.0
Host: example.com
```

However, it's kind of inconvenient to assemble these requests manually in your program, especially when you start doing things like sending parameters, encryption, etc. In this case, people should use some libraries on the machine. It's important that these are nonstandard. Probably one of the most common ones is `libcurl`.

[Here's a libcurl tutorial](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html). To summarize:

You can compile your program with libcurl by providing some flags to the compiler and the linker. You can get these by running `curl-config --cflags` and `curl-config --libs`.

Initialize libcurl with `curl_global_init(bitfield)`. The bitfield can have `CURL_GLOBAL_WIN32` and `CURL_GLOBAL_SSL` as its values. You probably need `CURL_GLOBAL_SSL` since you want to use encryption.

libcurl has two interfaces: `easy` and `multi`. I am going to cover `easy`.

Get an *easy handle* by calling `curl_easy_init()`. This handle allows you to make requests.

Set options on the handle by using `curl_easy_setopt(handle, option, value)`. `handle` is the "easy handle" you obtained, `option` is a constant - for example `CURLOPT_URL` for setting the URL to request - and `value` is the value you want to set it to. It's often a string.

Set a callback function with `option` as `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`. It should have the signature `size_t(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)`. It's called when libcurl receives data from the server. Usually, it's called many times. `nmemb` points out the size of the data in `buffer`. It should return the count of bytes it successfully processed. Normally this is `nmemb`.

Execute the request with `curl_easy_perform(handle)`.

When you're done with every request you want to make, call `curl_global_cleanup()`.

Answer (score 1):

Within [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_POSIX_library)  there is no part dedicated to `http2`.

However, working with `http2` in `C` is definitely possible, well documented and widely used. For example:

1. [curl](https://github.com/curl/curl) - info: https://curl.se/docs/http2.html
2. [nghttp2](https://www.nghttp2.org/)

More info about `http2` and various programming languages can be found here: https://github.com/httpwg/http2-spec/wiki/Implementations